# Weekly PDF generation using PHP and Highcharts

Tags: php, pdf, highcharts

My project uses Highcharts to generate all sorts of charts that are later used on dashboards and as the basis for various performance reports to the managers. A while ago the managers decided they want a big (probably, 50 or more pages) report generated weekly as a PDF document, and it has to include several charts that they are so used to by now.

I was wondering if it is possible to generate such a report (some images, text, tables, plus charts) automatically using PHP, for example, as a cron task that would start every Sunday midnight. I have never created PDFs using PHP, so I would be really grateful if someone could advise me on where to start.

1. What are the best classes for PDF generation using PHP that would include ability to insert images, text, tables, etc.?
2. How can I insert a Highcharts graph in the PDF that I am generating?
3. How should I approach generating a large PDF document (50+ pages)?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know somethign about the highcharts, but on their website I've seen, you can export the charts to an image, this is a way you could use to include them into your PDFs.

To create the PDFs you could checkout [pdfLIB](http://www.pdflib.com/en/products/pdflib-family/pdflib/), this can generate your PDFs out of the HTML site. So you only habe to generate a new View of your current page and render it as PDF via the library.

They also got a howto for PHPH: http://www.pdflib.com/en/developer/technical-documentation/pdflib-in-php-howto/

I hope this will help you generating your PDFs.

Comment: Using a html to pdf converter is a great idea.  Make sure the library you pick supports embedded SVG (since that's how highcharts renders the charts).  I do not know pdfLIB but would recommend wkhtmltopdf library.  Read this (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=689) which discusses how to use it when highcharts.